# How do I set up a targetting system in Java?

Tags: java

I am making a command-line game in Java to help learn better about GUI and such and I ran into a problem. In the game I want to be able to target another player. I am making a method called attack(). How would I go about, if I wanted to attack a player, bar, making it so that I could use attack(bar) as a function. I don't know how to reference an object in a parameter or an object created in a different class. What I need to my code to do is basically this: Assume my name is Player foo and I am attacking Player bar. Each player has 2 instance variables, `Player.playerHealth` and `Player.playerDamage` (the damage that they do). I need it to do:

```
attack(playerTarget) {
    target = playerTarget
    target.playerHealth = target.playerHealth - foo.playerDamage;  
}
```

So basically I need it to set the player losing health equal to the name in the parameters. How might I achieve this?

Comment: If you need to do it "by name" then make a function which takes a name and returns *the* Player object represented by that name. e.g. `playerWithName("Col. Mustard").attack(playerWithName("Mr. Green"))`. How this is done depends on how everything else works.

Comment: Your code snippet won't compile. Most of us programmer types are pretty OCD, and you have to be in order to be good at this stuff.  Please edit your post and add the method return type and parameter type, etc.

Comment: so, you're making a command-line game in Java to help learn better about GUI?

Comment: " I don't know how to reference an object in a parameter or an object created in a different class."  From the code you posted we really can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
public class Player {
    private int playerHealth;
    private int playerDamage;

    public void attack(Player target) {
        target.playerHealth -= this.playerDamage;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Player foo = new Player();
        foo.playerHealth = 10;
        foo.playerDamage = 1;

        Player bar = new Player();
        bar.playerHealth = 10;
        bar.playerDamage = 1;

        foo.attack(bar);
        foo.attack(bar);

        System.out.println(bar.playerHealth); // will print 8
    }
}
```

The attack method is declared on the Player class, so anytime you have a reference 'foo' to a Player, you can call attack in the following way: `foo.attack(otherPlayer)`.